# I need the sheet reference in the index to increase as a drag formula down line by line

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an index sheet that I need to get data into from the other sheets in the spreadsheet. The formula I have set up is ='I101'!$B$8 where the I101 is the sheet to get data from and the fixed cell B8.  However when I drag down this formula in the index sheet I need the 101 to increase by one and so as I drag the formula down.  However it stays fixed and I have to manually edit which is time consuming when you have the get data from 268 sheets.  How in this formula can i tell the next line down from I001 to skip to next sheet?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ROWS` function and `INDIRECT`. Let's assume you put the first formula in cell `C3` then use this version

`=INDIRECT("'I"&ROWS(C$3:C3)+100&"'!B8")`

as you drag down, the `ROWS` function increments and increases the number within your sheet name - that's more robust than using `ROW` function because this approach will still work if you add or delete rows above the formula.

Change the `C3s` depending on start cell